# What is wrong with my Power BI query (using a parameter)?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm brand new to using PBI but as far as I can tell, I should be able to substitute a parameter as part of a Direct Query in place of a hard-coded variable...ie

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("NAMEOFDB", "CMUtility", [Query="sp_get_residentsinfo "& home_name]),.....
```

instead of

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("NAMEOFDB", "CMUtility", [Query="sp_get_residentsinfo 'NAME OF HOME'"]),...
```

However, the parameter-included version just says

> DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near 'House'.
>   Details:
>       DataSourceKind=SQL
>       DataSourcePath=NAMEOFDB;CMUtility
>       Message=Incorrect syntax near 'House'.
>       Number=102
>       Class=15

"House" is the currently - assigned last word of the home_name variable. What have I done wrong?

PS - I have surmised that I shouldn't need the extra & at the end of the parameter, as I'm not adding anything else to the query, but even with both &s it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your parameters is `text`. In SQL, text literals must be quoted, i.e.  `sp_get_residentsinfo 'NAME OF HOME'`, but the statement build by you is `sp_get_residentsinfo NAME OF HOME`.

You should use [Text.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-replace) to escape single quotes in the parameter's value and append a quote before and after it.

Comment: D'oh! I don't know why I didn't spot that. Of course it would need to be quoted like SQL. Thanks very much. This now works.